# Deadlocks in a server that uses LiteDB

Tags: c#, server, deadlock, litedb

So I am writing a server in C#. It has a LiteDB database to store messages in. When I start up the server, I also launch an async task to delete expired messages from the DB (messages that are older than some predefined threshold). Lets call this task the GC (garbage collector).

Every time the server receives a message, it stores the message in the DB, and sends a copy to the proper destination.

Since LiteDB is supposed to be thread-safe, I don't use locks to synchronize reads/writes to the DB.

I've made a test (on a WPF app) that connects 100 clients, each in a separate task. Each client sends a message to all other clients and expects to receive a message from all other clients. I then make sure that all messages were sent/received as expected. During this test, the GC runs every 1 second (in the "real world" it will run once a week or something like that).

I observe some weird behavior in the test that I would love some help with.

In the first 1-3 seconds, things seem fine. The GC does a pass once a second, and between passes, many tasks (to send/receive messages) are running. Then, after these 1-3 seconds have passed, the GC does a pass, and then only one message is sent once a second (instead of many messages all at once). The GC task does not do a pass again.

Eventually, after 1 minute of this, I get the following exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'LiteDB.LiteException' in LiteDB.dll
Database lock timeout when entering in transaction mode after 00:01:00
```

I assume this means that I have a deadlock somewhere.
I've added a simplified version of my server's code.

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private static readonly TimeSpan _collectionInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    private static readonly TimeSpan _expirationThreshold = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
    
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Client> Clients = new();

    private readonly DBHandler _dbHandler = DBHandler.GetInstance(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Create a linked CTSource so that the garbage collection task could cancel
        // the entire operation in case of a fatal exception
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource =
            CancellationTokenSource
            .CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
        CancellationToken token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

        List<Task> GCAndConnectionsTasks = new();

        try
        {
            listener.Start();

            // Launch the garbage collection task to remove expired messages from the DB
            // Runs throughout the server's lifetime every (TimeSpan)_collectionInterval
            GCAndConnectionsTasks.Add(
                CollectExpiredMessagesAsync(
                    collectionInterval: _collectionInterval,
                    expirationThreshold: _expirationThreshold,
                    cancellationTokenSource // Allow task to cancel server
                )
            );

            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                TcpClient tcpClient = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync(token);

                // Handle the client connection in a separate task
                GCAndConnectionsTasks.Add(
                    HandleClientConnectionAsync(tcpClient, token)
                );
            }

            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            await Task.WhenAll(GCAndConnectionsTasks);
        }
        finally
        {
            _dbHandler.Dispose();
            listener.Stop();
            cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleClientConnectionAsync(TcpClient tcpClient, CancellationToken token)
    {
        Client? client = null;

        try
        {
            client = new(tcpClient);
            client.EnableKeepAlive();

            await SendMessageAsync(new WelcomeMessage(), client, token);

            DisconnectReason? reason = null;
            Message? message = await ReceiveMessageAsync(client, token);
            
            if (Clients.ContainsKey(message.FromStationID))
            {
                Clients.TryAdd(message.FromStationID, client);
                await ReceiveMessagesAsync(client, token);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clean up closed connection
            if (client is not null)
            {
                if (client.StationID is not null)
                {
                    Clients.TryRemove(client.StationID, out _);
                }
                client.CloseTcpAndStream();
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync(Client client, CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (client.IsConnected && !token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Message? message = await ReceiveMessageAsync(client, token);
            
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested || message is null)
            {
                break;
            }

            await ProcessMessageByTypeAsync(message, token);
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessMessageByTypeAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (message is null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (message is AckMessage ackMessage)
        {
            await ProcessAckMessageAsync(ackMessage, token);
        }
        else if (message is ComponentsMessage || message is FeedbackMessage)
        {
            await ProcessDataMessageAsync(message, token);
        }
        // Ignore other messages
    }

    private async Task ProcessDataMessageAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (message is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (message.ToStationID != null)
        {
            _dbHandler.Insert(message);

            Client client;

            if (Clients.TryGetValue(message.ToStationID, out client))
            {
                await SendMessageAsync(message, client, token);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessAckMessageAsync(AckMessage ackMessage, CancellationToken token)
    {
        _dbHandler.DeleteMessageByID(ackMessage.AckedMessageID);
    }

    private static async Task SendMessageAsync(Message message, Client client, CancellationToken token)
    {
        //use message.Serialize(), then add 4 byte header to create byte[] buffer
        
        await client.WriteAsync(buffer, token);
    }

    private static async Task<Message?> ReceiveMessageAsync(Client client, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // use await client.ReadAsync to receive 4 byte header
        // use await client.ReadAsync to receive the message bytes into byte[] buffer
        
        return
            buffer is null ?
            null :
            Message.Deserialize(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
    }

    private async Task CollectExpiredMessagesAsync(
        TimeSpan collectionInterval,
        TimeSpan expirationThreshold,
        CancellationTokenSource source)
    {
        while (!source.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Make sure GC has exclusive rights to the Messages of the DB.
            
            try
            {
                _dbHandler.DeleteExpiredMessages(expirationThreshold);
            }
            // Fatal error, cancel the entire operation (the server).
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                source.Cancel();
                throw;
            }
            

            if (!source.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Delay before the next garbage collection iteration
                await Task.Delay(collectionInterval, source.Token);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the relevant DB code:

```
private ILiteCollection<Message> GetCollection(Message message)
{
    var msgCollection = _dataBase
        .GetCollection<Message>(DB.MESSAGES);

    msgCollection.EnsureIndex((Message m) => m.MessageID);

    return msgCollection;
}

private ILiteCollection<Message> GetMessages()
{
    return GetCollection((Message)null);
}

public BsonValue Insert(Message message)
{
    message.MessageID = 0;
    message.TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
    return GetMessages()
        .Insert(message);
}

public bool DeleteMessageByID(BsonValue messageID)
{
    return GetMessages()
        .Delete(messageID);
}

public IEnumerable<Message> GetMessagesForStationID(string stationID)
{
    return GetMessages()
        .Find(message => message.ToStationID ==  stationID);
}

public int DeleteExpiredMessages(TimeSpan expirationThreshold)
{
    var cutoffTime = DateTime.UtcNow - expirationThreshold;
    return GetMessages()
        .DeleteMany((Message m) => m.TimeStamp < cutoffTime);
}
```

Comment: Wow, there is a lot going on ... as a first step, I'd say that this single class is doing much too much. Some of which is none of its business, actually. So, where do we start ... maybe you seem to have a `Client` class. Why not move all that message handling there? That should already simplify this `Worker` by a lot. Then I am not really sure if you actually need that ReaderWriterLock _at all_. Seems superfluent to me, so to start off with the _simplest_ possible solution, I'd just take that out and try.

Comment: For `CollectExpiredMessagesAsync` you may want to consider [PeriodicTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-7.0).

Comment: The problem, though could extend to the implementation of the `_dbHandler_` ...

Comment: Thanks! I originally wanted the lock to allow for consecutive DB accesses. For example, finding a message, and then deleting it. I wouldn't want the GC to run after finding and before deleting. However, I currently don't need it (changed to just deleting by ID), so I will test without it and update.

Could you explain why CollectExpiredMessagesAsync is better than Task.Delay?

Comment: _" Could you explain why CollectExpiredMessagesAsync is better than Task.Delay?"_ I don't understand? I suggested to have a look into PeriodicTimer, because what you handcrafted there seems pretty similar to what the PeriodicTimer gives you, just a little more conveniently. You don't _have to_, of course. I just thought it would be a good fit.

Comment: Oh no worries, I was just asking to understand. I will check it!

Added the _dbHandler code. Would love it if you can take a look!

Comment: _"For example, finding a message, and then deleting it."_ - This is really a no-problem. Why? - If you fetch it, you have the content, the data. You could immediatly delete the entry (if deletion is done unconditionally, anyway). So if the "GC" already deleted it, yeah so what - it's gone. Job done.

Comment: `private ILiteCollection<Message> GetCollection(Message message)` - that argument seems to be unused?

Comment: You are right that locking is unnecessary for the situation I described. I was, however, wondering if I may, in the future, encounter situations that require locking. Anyway, it does not really matter, as the problem is not actually the locking. I've completely removed any usage of the lock, and the problem presists!

So I guess it has to do with something related to LiteDB's own synchronization.

Comment: I will update the post to reflect this new information.

Comment: Umm, yeah. I just read, that a) You are supposed to use one `LiteDatabase` instance _per thread_ ... which surprises me. But the article could be somewhat older. And b) there are ACID transactions supported, actually: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5uy2Vr

Comment: Are you sure some existing protocol or message queue could not suitable for your purpose? "Receive, save a copy, route to receiver" sounds very message-queue-ish to me, and I would not be surprised if you could do the same by simply configuring some existing software.

Comment: "You are supposed to use one LiteDatabase instance per thread"
Could you explain what this means? Should I not use _dbHandler as a singleton?

Comment: Also, I think I may need to make a new post, seeing as the original post focused on the AsyncReaderWriterLock, which I don't use anymore and is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods 
I completely removed the GC task, and the issue still persists. So it probably is something to do with the way that I use LiteDB. After a while (1000-3000 messages), no new tasks are launched, and only 1 new task is launched every 1 second. I think I will make a new post. Hopefully it is ok to tag you there!

Comment: Sounds like a good idea if the question isn't the same question anymore :D

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods here it is:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76827659/litedb-deadlocks-i-may-be-using-litedb-wrong